# Comparing DateTime object in symfony (with propel)

Tags: datetime, symfony1, compare, propel

I want to compare two DateTime objects in php code. I'm using Symfony 1.4 with Propel.

```
$article = $obj->getArticle();
if($article->getVisibleFrom() <= new DateTime()) {
     DO_SOMETHING();
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting string from `getVisibleFrom()` getter (instead of `DateTime` object).
In database `visible_from` field is type of `DATETIME`.
I read that with Doctrine I could use function `getDateTimeObject('visible_from')`.

Comment: Problem solved :)
getVisibleFrom("U") <= time()          //getter returns unix timestamp
getVisibleFrom(null) <= new DateTime() //getter returns DateTime object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default behavior at build time by changing build properties: http://www.propelorm.org/reference/buildtime-configuration.html#datetime_settings

And here is the doc for the temporal getters: http://www.propelorm.org/reference/active-record.html#temporal_columns

William